# Spring Boot Application cannot run test cases involving Two Databases correctly - either get detached entities or no inserts

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I am trying to write a Spring Boot app that talks to two databases - `primary` which is read-write, and `secondary` which is read only.

This is also using spring-data-jpa for the repositories.

Roughly speaking this giude describes what I am doing: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

And this documentation from spring:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-two-datasources

I am having trouble understanding some things - I think about the transaction managers - which is making my program error out either during normal operation, or during unit tests.

I am running into two issues, with two different TransactionManagers that I do not understand well

1)

When I use `JPATransactionManager`, my secondary entities become detached between function calls.  This happens in my application running in full Spring boot Tomcat, and when running the JUnit test as SpringRunner.

2)

When I use `DataSourceTransactionManager` which was given in some tutorial my application works correctly, but when I try to run a test case with SpringRunner, without running the full server, spring/hibernate **will not perform any inserts or updates** on the primaryDataSource.

--

Here is a snippet of code for (1) form a service class.

```
@Transactional
public List<PrimaryGroup> synchronizeAllGroups(){
    Iterable<SecondarySite> secondarySiteList = secondarySiteRepo.findAll();
    List<PrimaryGroup> allUserGroups = new ArrayList<PrimaryGroup>(0);
    for( SecondarySite secondarySite: secondarySiteList){
        allUserGroups.addAll(synchronizeSiteGroups( secondarySite.getName(), secondarySite));
    }
    return allUserGroups;
}
@Transactional
public List<PrimaryGroup> synchronizeSiteGroups(String sitename, SecondarySite secondarySite){

    // GET all secondary groups
    if( secondarySite == null){
        secondarySite = secondarySiteRepo.getSiteByName(sitename);
    }

    logger.debug("synchronizeGroups started - siteId:{}", secondarySite.getLuid().toString());

    List<SecondaryGroup> secondaryGroups = secondarySite.getGroups();// This shows the error because secondarySite passed in is detached
    List<PrimaryGroup> primaryUserGroups = primaryGroupRepository.findAllByAppName(sitename);
    ...
    // modify existingUserGroups to have new data from secondary
    ...
    primaryGroupRepository.save(primaryUserGroups );
    logger.debug("synchronizeGroups complete");
    return existingUserGroups;
}
```

I am pretty sure I understand what is going on with the detached entities with JPATransactionManager -- When populateAllUsers calls populateSiteUser, it is only carrying over the `primaryTransactionManager` and the secondary one gets left out, so the entities become detached.  I can probably work around that, but I'd like to see if there is any way to have this work, without putting all calls to `secondary*` into a seperate service layer, that returns non-managed entities.

--

Here is a snippet of code for (2) from a controller class

```
@GetMapping("synchronize/secondary")
public String synchronizesecondary() throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    synchronizeAllGroups(); // pull all the groups
    synchronizeAllUsers(); // pull all the users
    synchronizeAllUserGroupMaps(); // add the mapping table
    return "true";
}
```

This references that same `synchronizeAllGroups` from above.  But when I am useing `DataSourceTransactionManager` I do not get that detached entity error.
What I do get instead, is that the `primaryGroupRepository.save(primaryUserGroups );` call **does not generate any insert or update statement** - when running a JUnit test that calls the controller directly.   So when `synchronizeAllUserGroupMaps` gets called, primaryUserRepository.findAll() returns 0 rows, and same with primaryGroupRepository

That is to say - it works when I run this test case:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)

@SpringBootTest(classes=app.DApplication.class,  properties={"spring.profiles.active=local,embedded"})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class MockTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @Test
    public void shouldSync() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/admin/synchronize/secondary")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }


}
```

But it does not do any inserts or updates when I run this test case:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)

@SpringBootTest(classes=app.DApplication.class,  properties={"spring.profiles.active=local,embedded"}, webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired AdminController adminController;
    @Test
    public void shouldSync() throws Exception {
        String o = adminController.synchronizesecondary();
    }
}
```

---

Here are the two configuration classes
Primary:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = app.primary.dao.BasePackageMarker.class )
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        transactionManagerRef = "dataSourceTransactionManager",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "primaryEntityManagerFactory",
        basePackageClasses = { app.primary.dao.BasePackageMarker.class }
        )
public class PrimaryConfig {

    @Bean(name = "primaryDataSourceProperties")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.primary.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties primaryDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "primaryDataSource")
    @Primary
    public DataSource primaryDataSourceEmbedded() {
        return primaryDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();

    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean primaryEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("primaryDataSource") DataSource primaryDataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(primaryDataSource)
                .packages(app.primary.dao.BasePackageMarker.class)
                .persistenceUnit("primary")
                .build();
    }
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager( @Qualifier("primaryDataSource") DataSource primaryDataSource) {
        DataSourceTransactionManager txm  = new DataSourceTransactionManager(primaryDataSource);
        return txm;
    }

}
```

And Secondary:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses=app.secondary.dao.BasePackageMarker.class ) /* scan secondary as secondary database */
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        transactionManagerRef = "secondaryTransactionManager",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "secondaryEntityManagerFactory",
        basePackageClasses={app.secondary.dao.BasePackageMarker.class}

        )
public class SecondaryConfig {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecondaryConfig.class);

    @Bean(name = "secondaryDataSourceProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.secondary.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties secondaryDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondaryDataSource")
    public DataSource secondaryDataSourceEmbedded() {
        return secondaryDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();

    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean secondaryEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("secondaryDataSource") DataSource secondaryDataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(secondaryDataSource)
                .packages(app.secondary.dao.BasePackageMarker.class)
                .persistenceUnit("secondary")
                .build();
    }
    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager secondaryTransactionManager( @Qualifier("secondaryDataSource") DataSource secondaryDataSource) {
        DataSourceTransactionManager txm  = new DataSourceTransactionManager(secondaryDataSource);
        return txm;
    }


}
```

In my real application, the secondary data source - since it is read-only - is used during real run time, and during the unit test I am writing.

I have been having trouble getting spring to initialize both data sources, so I have not attached a complete example.

thanks for any insight people an give me.

Edit: I  have read some things that say to use Jta Transaction Manager when using multiple databases, and I have tried that.  I get an error when it tries to run the transaction on my second read-only database when I go to commit to the first database

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: prepared transactions are disabled
  Hint: Set max_prepared_transactions to a nonzero value.
```

In my case, I cannot set that, because the database is a read-only datbase provided by a vendor, we cannot change anything, and I really sho9udn't be trying to include this database as part of transactions, I just want to be able to call both databases in one service call.

Comment: You have the method annotated with @Transactional this means it uses the primary transaction manager. Is that really what you want?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli - Because the other database is readonly, the only database that needs transaction functionality is the primary database.  I believe that is the problem using JpaTransacitonManager, the entities for the second datasource get detached in calls from one `@transactional` function to another, since it is only the primaryTransactionmanager that is active.

Comment: Yes this is the behavoir

Comment: @SimonMartinelli - this does appear to be the behavior with `JpaTransactionManager`.   What i would like to find out is why the same code does not throw this error with `DataSourcetransactionManager`, and wether ther are any supported ways to explicitly allow the read-only database to maintain the session, throughout the read-write databases transactions.